# Angularjs passing variables from controller to dao service

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to pass a variable from the controller to my DAO service in an Angularjs application (frontend) and nodejs backend.

here is my controller :

```
    $scope.afficherProfils = function() {
    $http.get(configuration.URL_REQUEST + '/profile')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.owner = data._id;
            console.log('$scope.owner =========>');
            console.log($scope.owner);
            $http.get(configuration.URL_REQUEST + '/listerProfil', {
                owner: $scope.owner
            })
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log('$scope.listeProfils =========>');
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.listeProfils = data;
                });
        });
};
```

i am calling /profile to get the _id of the account that has added the profile, after that i call /listerProfil inside success and pass the owner parameter.

and in my DAO service the code is the following :

```
 exports.all = function(req, res) {
  console.log('req.body ================================>');
  console.log(req.body);
  Profil.find({
    owner: req.body.owner
  }, function(err, profils) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        'result': 'error'
      });
    } else {
      res.send(profils);
    }
  });
};
```

and i don't know why my req.body is empty when i do a console.log

any ideas ?

Comment: Use $http.post to send the data in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP-CRUD(Create-$http.post,Read-$http.get,Update-$http.put,Dlete-$http.delet)

```
$http.get-It used to get the value means this body contain empty value

$http.post-It used to create value means this body contain data (your are post some data to server)

$http.update-It used to update exit value this body also contain data

$http.delete-It used to delete exit value this body contain empty(send through param(?id=1111))
```

so change your code http.get to http.post